# Why can urlopen download a Google search page but not a Google Scholar search page?

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib, google-scholar

I'm using **Python 3.2.3's** `urllib.request` module to download Google search results, but I'm getting an odd error in that `urlopen` works with links to Google search results, but not Google Scholar. In this example, I'm searching for `"JOHN SMITH"`. This code successfully prints HTML:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen, Request
from urllib.error import URLError

# Google
try:
    page_google = '''http://www.google.com/#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22JOHN+SMITH%22&oq=%22JOHN+SMITH%22&gs_l=hp.3..0l4.129.2348.0.2492.12.10.0.0.0.0.154.890.6j3.9.0...0.0...1c.gjDBcVcGXaw&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=dffb3b4a4179ca7c&biw=1366&bih=649'''
    req_google = Request(page_google)
    req_google.add_header('User Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:15.0) Gecko/20120427 Firefox/15.0a1')
    html_google = urlopen(req_google).read()
    print(html_google[0:10])
except URLError as e:
    print(e)
```

but this code, doing the same for Google Scholar, raises a `URLError` exception:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen, Request
from urllib.error import URLError

# Google Scholar
try:
    page_scholar = '''http://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=%22JOHN+SMITH%22&btnG=&as_sdt=1%2C14'''
    req_scholar = Request(page_scholar)
    req_scholar.add_header('User Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:15.0) Gecko/20120427 Firefox/15.0a1')
    html_scholar = urlopen(req_scholar).read()
    print(html_scholar[0:10])
except URLError as e:
    print(e)
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ak5791/Desktop/code-sandbox/scholar/crawler.py", line 6, in <module>
    html = urlopen(page).read()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/urllib/request.py", line 138, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/urllib/request.py", line 369, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/urllib/request.py", line 387, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/urllib/request.py", line 347, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/urllib/request.py", line 1155, in http_open
    return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/urllib/request.py", line 1138, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno -5] No address associated with hostname>
```

I obtained these links by searching in Chrome and copying the link from there. One commenter reported a 403 error, which I sometimes get as well. I presume this is because Google doesn't support scraping of Scholar. However, changing the User Agent string doesn't fix this *or the original problem*, since I get `URLErrors` most of the time.

Comment: I get a 403 (Forbidden), which probably means Google does not want you to scrape information from Scholar searches.  The terms of service might disallow this (I did not check them).

Comment: @SvenMarnach I updated the question, since I tried changing the User Agent string. Sometimes I get a `URLError`, and sometimes I get a 403 error. Most of the time I get the former, however.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This PHP script](https://code.google.com/p/bioguid/source/browse/trunk/www/scholar_ris.php) seems to indicate you'll need to set some cookies before Google gives you results:

```
/*

 Need a cookie file (scholar_cookie.txt) like this:

# Netscape HTTP Cookie File
# http://curlm.haxx.se/rfc/cookie_spec.html
# This file was generated by libcurl! Edit at your own risk.

.scholar.google.com     TRUE    /       FALSE   2147483647      GSP     ID=353e8f974d766dcd:CF=2
.google.com     TRUE    /       FALSE   1317124758      PREF    ID=353e8f974d766dcd:TM=1254052758:LM=1254052758:S=_biVh02e4scrJT1H
.scholar.google.co.uk   TRUE    /       FALSE   2147483647      GSP     ID=f3f18b3b5a7c2647:CF=2
.google.co.uk   TRUE    /       FALSE   1317125123      PREF    ID=f3f18b3b5a7c2647:TM=1254053123:LM=1254053123:S=UqjRcTObh7_sARkN

*/
```

This is corroborated by [Python recipe for Google Scholar comment](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/523047-search-google-scholar/#c2), which includes a warning that Google detects scripts and will disable you if you use it too prolifically.

Comment: The Python recipe is great, albeit a bit outdated since the HTML layout of the results page has since changed. With a few tweaks, though, it's working exactly as needed.

Comment: I hate to link this question to a new question, but do you have any idea why the cookie you describe there doesn't validate as a proper cookie? I've been trying to [figure that out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11529428/why-does-python-say-this-netscape-cookie-file-isnt-valid), since it's holding up my entire application.