# Importing data from google scholar(bibtex) using cookies

Tags: python, firefox, cookies

The following is the code :

```
import cookielib
import urllib2 
from bs4 import  BeautifulSoup

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:30.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/30.0'}
url='http://scholar.google.co.in/scholar_setprefs?sciifh=1&scisig=AAGBfm0AAAAAU9jcmEN2h2yuBuZqQK8Es5dQG3ksjutw&inststart=0&num=10&scis=yes&scisf=4&hl=en&lang=all&instq=&save='

filename = "cookies.txt"
request = urllib2.Request(url, None, headers)
cookies = cookielib.MozillaCookieJar(filename, None, None)
cookies.load()
cookie_handler= urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cookies)
redirect_handler= urllib2.HTTPRedirectHandler()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(redirect_handler,cookie_handler)
response = opener.open(request)
print response.read()
```

Output Error :

```
C:\Python27\lib\_MozillaCookieJar.py:109: UserWarning: cookielib bug!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\_MozillaCookieJar.py", line 71, in _really_load
    line.split("\t")
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

  _warn_unhandled_exception()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\new user\Desktop\pythonprac\working\googlescholar.py", line 10, in <module>
    cookies.load()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\cookielib.py", line 1763, in load
    self._really_load(f, filename, ignore_discard, ignore_expires)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\_MozillaCookieJar.py", line 111, in _really_load
    (filename, line))
cookielib.LoadError: invalid Netscape format cookies file 'cookies.txt': '.scholar.google.com     TRUE    /       FALSE   2147483647      GSP     ID=353e8f974d766dcd:CF=2'
```

This code has been sourced from net and i am trying to download the data from google scholar bibtex data into a txt file. For this purpose, I am need to save the user settings into a cookie. I am writing the data into cookie.txt. But I get the above error.
Please guide on how to handle this cookie error and how to use cookies to save the user defined preferences for google.scolar.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May I suggest to use another set of libraries?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url= 'http://scholar.google.co.in/scholar_setprefs?sciifh=1&' +\
     'scisig=AAGBfm0AAAAAU9jcmEN2h2yuBuZqQK8Es5dQG3ksjutw' +\
     '&inststart=0&num=10&scis=yes&scisf=4&hl=en&lang=all&instq=&save='

page = requests.get(url)
cookies = page.cookies

page = requests.get(url, cookies=cookies)

print page.content
```

With `cookies = page.cookies` I retrieve the cookies and save it to the `cookies` variable. I re-request the same page passing that variable. If you have the `cookies.txt` file, you can load it as a dict

---

If you want to do it with the Standard Library urllib2 and cookielib, make sure the first line in the cookies.txt file is

```
# Netscape HTTP Cookie File
```

Or else cookielib won't load it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11536599/1688590